# OpenStack API - cURL request hypervisor information

Tags: curl, openstack, hypervisor

I am making some HTTP requests using cURL to the OpenStack API to gather information about my OpenStack deployment.
I have used "http://api.openstack.org/" for the URI information about different sets of requests. However, I need information about the hypervisor: its IP addresses etc. I have not been able to find a way to access hypervisor information from the OpenStack cloud I have deployed.

To try different things, I looked at the URIs used in the python nova-client documentation and it recently added the OpenStack hypervisor information option and it uses the URI like "/os-hypervisors/detail/" but this does not work for me. It simply gives me an HTTP 404 error.

Can somebody please help me find a way to get the hypervisor information (IP addresses at least) using cURL requests?

NOTE: I am using the OpenStack Diablo Release. I have all the services running except for nova-volume and Swift.

P.S. If you need more information, please let me know. I will be happy to provide you with that. I really need to get this working.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I am not sure those API queries existed in Diablo.  You may want to upgrade.  There have been many advances since diablo.  In fact the grizzly release is nearing completion right now.  It's a very good time to consider upgrading.

Alternatively you can tie into a backend monitoring system to query libvirt directly.  I've done this before to great success.  I've used nagios style plugins to query libvirt on nodes via NRPE and return information.  And NRPE can be used outside of simple nagios reporting environments to provide custom reporting data sets.